# More efficient way to get MySQL data?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am using: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql to be able to access my db through javascript.
This is my current code:

```
connection.query(`SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = '${userID}';`, function (error, rows, fields) {
  if (error) errorHandler(msg, error);
  rows = JSON.stringify(rows);
  moneyArray = [];
  moneyArray = JSON.parse(rows);
  console.log(`Your cash: ` + moneyArray[0].cash);
});
```

Since rows returns `[ RowDataPacket { cash: 0 } ]` I had to stringify it to be able to use it, but then I parsed it back into a normal array to actually be able to get the data from it. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to handle the RowDataPacket data because stringifying and parsing it every time I need to pull data seems inefficient.

Comment: There's no need to stringify and parse the result. You can just use `rows`

Comment: @baao You can't. That's what I was originally trying to do.

Comment: Of course you can, just look at the very first example on the repo you linked to. Please post your non working code without the stringify / parse

Comment: @baao is completely right. It may look like that in the logs, but calling row.cash will work the exact same. Source: used node-mysql for 4 years.

Comment: `row.cash` won't @PaulBGD, but `rows[0].cash` will

Comment: @baao I'm aware, just showing sample usage on a RowDataPacket object.

Comment: ES6 introduces string interpolation and now JavaScript people are jumping on the [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) bandwagon. **DON'T** do this. Use prepared statements with placeholder values. A library like [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) makes this really easy to do.